# Exception Unable to parse the date while using parseDateStrictly() method of DateUtils class

Tags: java, date, datetime

getting following exception for following code, exception doesn't come if i use parseDate() method, i dont understand what is the reason.

> Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unable to parse
>   the date: 03/22/2012:00:00:00     at
>   org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils.parseDateWithLeniency(DateUtils.java:336)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils.parseDateStrictly(DateUtils.java:286)

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        String testDate="03/22/2012:00:00:00";
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");    
        System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(DateUtils.parseDateStrictly(testDate, new String[]{"MM/dd/yyyy:hh:mm:ss","MM-dd-yyyy","MM/dd/yyyy",
               "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss","yyyy-MM-dd","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"})));    
    } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Format pattern must be "MM/dd/yyyy:HH:mm:ss".

lower case hh if for `Hour in am/pm (1-12)`

upper case HH is for `Hour in day (0-23)`

For more Informations see the javadoc of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Thanks @Jens . understood now.